# left join result of two union

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

Trying to join those two information and create a new table. My goal is to add create year and month table

For example

```
t1 is
Year
1990
1991
1992

t2 is
Jan
Feb 
Mar
```

I want all the possible combinations in one table.

```
1990-Jan
1990-Feb
1990-Mar
1991-Jan
1992-Feb...
```

thats why i didnt put any conditions on my code.

```
   SELECT b.year
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT year from barcelona.births
    UNION 
    SELECT year from barcelona.immigrants_by_age
    )
    AS b
left join a.month,
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT month 
    from barcelona.unemployment
    UNION 
    SELECT month from barcelona.accidents
    )
    AS a
;
```

Comment: What fields are you planning to join the tables on?

Comment: That's not even a valid SQL syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You might be surprised to learn that a non-functioning query is not really a good way to communicate what you want to do.

Comment: Posting a broken query without telling us what you want to do will not help us help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name (create_year, create_month) 
    SELECT t1.create_year, t2.create_month FROM t1, t2
```

In case you want to concat the values together you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name (create_year_month) 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', t1.create_year, t2.create_month) FROM t1, t2
```

Using a `JOIN` (or like on the solution `,`) without a condition (without `ON`) creates every possible combination between the rows of the two tables. By using a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` you can `SELECT` and `INSERT` the selected values in one query into the new table.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba9c09e832b718e526102e09007cc436)

---

Your query should look like the following:

```
SELECT b.`year`, a.`month`
FROM (
    SELECT `year` FROM barcelona.births
    UNION 
    SELECT `year` FROM barcelona.immigrants_by_age
) AS b, (
    SELECT `month` FROM barcelona.unemployment
    UNION 
    SELECT `month` from barcelona.accidents
) AS a
```